# Terraform: Launch individual functionalities without copying providers file in every folder

Tags: terraform

Given the following directory structure:

```
├── modules
│   ├── providers.tf
│   ├── rds
│   │   ├── rds.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── VirtualMachine
│       ├── vm.tf
```

I have a common providers file that defines access to the environment. Besides, there are different functionalities like create a Virtual machine or a RDS.

My question is: how can I launch individual functionalities, like just the virtual machine, **without copying the providers.tf inside of every folder**.

There is a workaround using symlinks that referrers the providers.tf but it isn't a proper solution.

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence? That you don't understand how symlinks work? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Updated.There is a workaround using symlinks that referrers the providers.tf but it isn't a proper solution.

Comment: The root module typically defines the provider.

Comment: What do you mean by it isn't a proper solution? What would your ideal solution look like ignored technical constraints?

Comment: The point is I want to deploy infrastructure as demand per functionality (i.e. a virtual machine). When I move to the folder where the code is allowed it can not identify the providers.tf root cause is a level down in the directory level.